# Can Octopus Deploy choose an unused environment?

Tags: continuous-integration, octopus-deploy, concourse

Is it possible to have Octopus Deploy make a deployment to an environment/deployment target that is not currently 'in use'?

I've used CI systems like Concourse in which it's possible to create a pool of environments, and then have each run of a CI pipeline 'check out' and environment from the pool. When an environment is checked out, no other runs of that pipeline can use that environment, ensuring test isolation. When the run is finished, it returns that environment to the pool.

Does Octopus Deploy have such a feature? Has anyone achieved similar outcomes either with Octopus primitives or custom scripting?